# A dictionary with string of key and a list of value to a list

Tags: python

I want to convert the following dictionary to a simple list:

```
dict1 = {'fred': ['andrew', 'judy'], 'andrew': ['judy', 'george'], 'judy': ['george'], 'george': ['john']}
```

I have tried:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    output = [key, value]
    list1.append(output)

ls2 = []
for x in list1:
    for y in x:
        ls2.append(y)
print(ls2)

so I got ls2 = ['fred', ['andrew', 'judy'], 'andrew', ['judy', 'george'], 'judy', ['george'], 'george', ['john']]
```

How do I get the expected output as:

```
[['fred', 'andrew', 'judy'], ['andrew','judy', 'george'], ['judy', 'george'], ['george', 'john']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work under python 2 or 3 you can do:

#### Code:

```
[[k] + v for k, v in dict1.items()]
```

#### Test Code:

```
dict1 = {'fred': ['andrew', 'judy'], 'andrew': ['judy', 'george'],
         'judy': ['george'], 'george': ['john']}

desired = [
    ['fred', 'andrew', 'judy'],
    ['andrew', 'judy', 'george'],
    ['judy', 'george'],
    ['george', 'john']
]

x = [[k] + v for k, v in dict1.items()]
print(x)
```

#### Results:

```
[['judy', 'george'], ['george', 'john'], ['andrew', 'judy', 'george'], ['fred', 'andrew', 'judy']]
```

Answer (score 3):

### **`list comprehension`** and **`*splat`**

```
x = [[k, *v] for k, v in dict1.items()]

# Result

[['fred', 'andrew', 'judy'], ['andrew', 'judy', 'george'], ['judy', 'george'], ['george', 'john']]
```

Comment: Correct, can't use unpacking like this in py2

Comment: I grabbed your comments and modified my answer. I have provided working examples for both **Python2** and **Python3** using `map()`, `lambda` function, `umpacking` list etc. Thanks very much for your updates.

Comment: You just copied the 2 current answers into your own answer and made them worse.  Seems to be zero point to doing so.

Comment: **@chrisz**, no it looks like that I  have copied the answers but I first tried it in online editing website named  `rextester.com` then I was about to paste it to stackoverflow. I saw your answer which was similar to me. So I thought to use another way to do the same. Finally I used **map()** and **lambda** function & presented example for both **Python2** and **Python3**.

Answer (score -1):

**@Louis**, you can also use `map()` and `lambda` function to solve your problem. I have provided working examples for **Python3** and **Python2** both as **Python2** throws **SyntaxError** if you use `*` to unpack lists.

You can check it in the below code example (I have shown 2 ways including the above solution).

> **Note**: Use `json` module to pretty print your list if it's large and you want to see it in console.

### Python3 (Python 3.5.2)

```
import json

dict1 = {'fred': ['andrew', 'judy'], 'andrew': ['judy', 'george'], 'judy': ['george'], 'george': ['john']}

# 1st way...
l = [[name, *name_list] for name, name_list in dict1.items()]

# pretty printing list
print (json.dumps(l, indent=4))

# 2nd way...
l2 = list(map( lambda name: [name, *dict1[name]],  dict1.keys()))
print(l2)

"""
[
    [
        "fred",
        "andrew",
        "judy"
    ],
    [
        "judy",
        "george"
    ],
    [
        "george",
        "john"
    ],
    [
        "andrew",
        "judy",
        "george"
    ]
]
"""
```

The above code will throw **SyntaxError** if you will run it using **Python2**. Below is the fixed and working just after a little bit of modification made to the above code.

### Python2 (Python 2.7.12)

```
import json

dict1 = {'fred': ['andrew', 'judy'], 'andrew': ['judy', 'george'], 'judy': ['george'], 'george': ['john']}

# 1st way...
l = [[name] + [name_item for name_item in name_list] for name, name_list in dict1.items()]

# pretty printing list
print (json.dumps(l, indent=4))

# 2nd way...
l2 = list(map( lambda name: [name] + [name_item for name_item in dict1[name]], dict1.keys()))
print(l2)

"""
[
    [
        "fred",
        "andrew",
        "judy"
    ],
    [
        "judy",
        "george"
    ],
    [
        "george",
        "john"
    ],
    [
        "andrew",
        "judy",
        "george"
    ]
]
"""
```